# Hostgator server. Contact_us made using PHP_Mailer / google SMTP server. No error but messages not sent

Tags: smtp, composer-php, gmail, phpmailer, contact-form

I created contact_us form using PHP_Mailer and SMTP server (gmail.smtp.server). On localhost it works perfectly. But when I uploaded site files on server. It says "mail sent successfully" but no mail's in my gmail account (I pointed it in code as receiever). On server I have access only to root folder where I uploaded my site files.

```
  require "vendor/autoload.php";

// Include packages and files for PHPMailer and SMTP protocol

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/SMTP.php';

// Initialize PHP mailer, configure to use SMTP protocol and add credentials

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";

$mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;
$mail->SMTPAuth   = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";
require_once 'folder/video.php';
$mail->Username = SMTP_USERNAME;
$mail->Password = SMTP_PASSWORD;

$success = "";
$error = "";
$name = $message = $email = "";
$errors = array('name' => '', 'email' => '', 'message' => '');

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (empty(trim($_POST["name"]))) {
        $errors['name'] = "Your name is required";
    } else {
        $name = SanitizeString($_POST["name"]);
        if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z\s]{2,50}$/', $name)) {
            $errors['name'] = "Only letters and spaces allowed";
        }
    }

    if (empty(trim($_POST["email"]))) {
        $errors["email"] = "Your email is required";
    } else {
        $email = SanitizeString($_POST["email"]);
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errors["email"] = "Please give a proper email address";
        }
    }

    if (empty(trim($_POST["message"]))) {
        $errors["message"] = "Please type your message";
    } else {
        $message = SanitizeString($_POST["message"]);
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z\d\s]+$/", $message)) {
            $errors["message"] = "Only letters, spaces and maybe numbers allowed";
        }
    }

    if (array_filter($errors)) {
    } else {
        try {

            $mail->setFrom($email, $name);

            $mail->addAddress("mail@gmail.com", "My name");

            $mail->Subject = 'new message';

            $mail->Body = $message;

            // send mail

            $mail->send();

            // empty users input

            $name = $message = $email = "";

            $success = "Message sent successfully";
        } catch (Exception $e) {

            // echo $e->errorMessage(); use for testing & debugging purposes
            $error = "Sorry message could not send, try again";
        } catch (Exception $e) {

            // echo $e->getMessage(); use for testing & debugging purposes
            $error = "Sorry message could not send, try again";
        }
    }
}

function SanitizeString($var)
{
    $var = strip_tags($var);
    $var = htmlentities($var);
    return stripslashes($var);
}
```

It works perfectly on localhost

screenshot of folder available on server (white screenshot)
[image]

folders in my VScodeStudio
[image]

Comment: Why is this tagged with Composer? Are you sure your problem is related to Composer itself? Also, what have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure, that was one of the assumptions.
up to this moment, I've tried to install PHPmailer to server (I have access only to root folder) - no effect.
After speaking to support I've changed host creds (`$mail->SMTPSecure = "false";
$mail->Port       = 25;
$mail->Host       = "127.0.0.1";`)
Now this error appears:

Comment: `2023-05-28 19:50:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO adskitstudio.com
2023-05-28 19:50:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): Peer certificate CN=`*.win.hostgator.com' did not match expected CN=`127.0.0.1'
2023-05-28 19:50:58 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2023-05-28 19:50:58 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting`

Comment: support told me"You must correct this in the coding, and have the application log into SMTP, perform the send, and then disconnect in order for the mail to be sent correctly.  The server is accepting the connection, but the coding is not sending in the correct manner."
But for now I have no idea how to...
It all works on local host...

Comment: add all the clarifications to your question by editing it, don't place them in comments.

Comment: Read [the docs on connectivity and encryption problems](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host). You can see the certificate name mismatch in the error message.